# Update iPhones over the air with private server

Tags: ios, server.app, ipsw

I've a more than 20 iPhone 5s/6/6s in my company. I normally download IPSW and update using iTunes so that the updates do not take all the internet bandwidth.

I would like to know if it's possible create our own server and publish those updates such that users can update their phone by Wi-Fi. That way instead of downloading updates directly from Apple it will download from my private server.

Comment: Are you using [Apple's MDM solution](https://support.apple.com/business)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the Caching service, part of [server.app](/questions/tagged/server.app). The Caching service supports OTA updates for iOS 7 and later. All you need to do is enable the service in Server.app. Devices do not need to be part of MDM supervision.

> macOS and iOS devices automatically access the available caching service on the network they’re currently connected to

You can find Apple's documentation of the Caching service at:

- https://help.apple.com/serverapp/mac/#/apd74DDE89F-08D2-4E0A-A5CD-155E345EFB83